# How to update Formview.SelectCommand programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to ASP.NET and C#, trying to convert an old MS Access multi-tabbed form with a SQL Server backend to ASP.NET / C#. In place of the 8 tabs I’ve created 8 webpages and a master page that contains the navigation bar. Each webpage has a FormView with its own SQLDataSource. As I navigate from one page to the next, I want to change the SQL “recordsource” for the given txtClientFileCode and txtWOJob. I’m getting an error where I try to update the SelectCommand at fvWriteUp.DataBind(): System.Data.OleDbException “syntax error, permission, or other nonspecific error”

Can anyone help? See what I’m doing wrong, offer suggestions? I’ve been working on this conversion for months and am about ready to throw in the towel. Thanks in advance.

```
WriteUp SQLDataSource
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceWU" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringWU %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringWU.ProviderName %>"            
        SelectCommand="spWriteUpSel" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
        UpdateCommand="spWriteUpUpd" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
        InsertCommand="spWriteUpIns" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure"            
        DeleteCommand="spWriteUpDel" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure">

        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="txtClientFileCode" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="txtWOJobCode" Type="String" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="txtWOJobCode" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="txtClientFileCode" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="txtWOStatusCode" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="txtWOJob" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="dtmReqDate" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="txtFunds" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="dtmAssignDate" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="dtmStartDate" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="dtmComplDate" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="dblEstCost" Type="Double" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="dblClientPaid" Type="Double" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="dblTotalCost" Type="Double" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ysnPartB" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="txtClientFirst" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="txtClientLast" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="txtClientAddr1" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="txtClientAdd2" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="txtClientCity" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="txtClientState" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="txtClientZip" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="txtClientPhone" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="txtWOJobCode" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="txtClientFileCode" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="txtWOStatusCode" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="txtWOJob" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="dtmReqDate" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="txtFunds" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="dtmAssignDate" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="dtmStartDate" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="dtmComplDate" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="dblEstCost" Type="Double" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="dblClientPaid" Type="Double" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="dblTotalCost" Type="Double" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ysnPartB" Type="Boolean" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="txtClientFirst" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="txtClientLast" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="txtClientAddr1" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="txtClientAdd2" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="txtClientCity" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="txtClientState" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="txtClientZip" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="txtClientPhone" Type="String" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

MasterPage
protected void mnuMainMenu_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
    {            
            switch (e.Item.Value)
            {
                case "QuickView":
                    //Server.Transfer("QuickView.aspx");
                    Response.Redirect("~/QuickView");
                    break;
                case "WriteUp":
                    //Server.Transfer("WriteUp.aspx");
                    Response.Redirect("~/WriteUp");
                    break;


WritUp page. (I’ve validated that the Select statement works in a SQL Server View.)

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string ClientFileCode = (string)(Session["sesClientFileCode"]);
            string WOJob = (string)(Session["sesWOJob"]);

            SqlDataSourceWU.SelectCommand = "SELECT tblWorkOrders.txtClientFileCode, tblWorkOrders.txtWOJob," +
                "tblWorkOrders.txtWOStatusCode, tblWorkOrders.txtWOJobCode, tblWorkOrders.dtmReqDate, " +
                "tblWorkOrders.dtmAssignDate, tblWorkOrders.dtmStartDate, tblWorkOrders.dtmComplDate, " +
                "tblWorkOrders.dblEstCost, tblWorkOrders.ysnPartB, tblWorkOrders.dblClientPaid, " +
                "tblWorkOrders.dblTotalCost,tblClient.txtFundCode, tblClient.txtClientFirst, tblClient.txtClientLast, " +
                "tblClient.txtClientAddr1, tblClient.txtClientAdd2, tblClient.txtClientCity, " +
                "tblClient.txtClientState, tblClient.txtClientZip, tblClient.txtClientPhone, " +
                "tblClient.txtClientFirst + ' ' + tblClient.txtClientLast AS txtClientName, " +
                "tblFunding.txtFundSource, tblWOStatus.txtWOStatusDescrip " +
                "FROM tblWorkOrders INNER JOIN " +
                "tblClient ON tblWorkOrders.txtClientFileCode = tblClient.txtClientFileCode " +
                "INNER JOIN tblFunding ON tblClient.txtFundCode = tblFunding.txtFundCode " +
                "INNER JOIN tblWOStatus ON tblWorkOrders.txtWOStatusCode = tblWOStatus.txtWOStatusCode " +
                "WHERE " +
                "(tblWorkOrders.txtClientFileCode = '" + ClientFileCode + "')" +
                " AND (tblWorkOrders.txtWOJob = " + Convert.ToInt32(WOJob) + ")";
            SqlDataSourceWU.DataBind();
            fvWriteUp.DataBind();
        }
```

Comment: Still stuck on this. If anyone has suggestions on other places to ask this question, I'd love to know. Thanks.

Comment: This is working for me: 

In my aspx file I added 
<SelectParameters>
   <asp:Parameter Name="txtClientFileCode" Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="txtWOJob" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>

In my stored procedure I added 
(@txtClientFileCode varchar(4),
@txtWOJob int)

In C# behind Page_Load I replaced the assignment of SqlDataSourceWU.SelectCommand with 
SqlDataSourceWU.SelectParameters["txtClientFileCode"].DefaultValue = ClientFileCode;
SqlDataSourceWU.SelectParameters["txtWOJob"].DefaultValue = Convert.ToString(WOJob);

and I kept fvWriteUp.DataBind();